# Saving Issue Custom Field Values via Rake Task in Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, redmine, redmine-plugins

Hi I have a rake task which when executed via console work, but doesn't work when rake task is called. Actually it confirms that save occurred, while values aren't updated. Seems like some active record commit is missing, because the only difference in logs I see is begin commit dumps if run (via console), while there isn't such sections in Redmine's debug.log when run as rake task...

Here is it's content:

```
namespace :redmine do
  namespace :myplugin do
    desc 'Updates custom field for idle tickets.'
    task :update_idle => :environment do
      Issue.open.each do |issue|
        begin
          days = DateTime.now.to_time - DateTime.parse(issue.updated_on.to_s).to_time
          days = days/86400
          if days > 0
            cfv = issue.custom_field_values.detect {|cfv| cfv.custom_field_id == 19 }
            cfv.value = days.ceil
            if issue.save
              puts "#{issue.id} saved"
            else
              puts "#{issue.id} not saved"
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If you don't change the issue attributes but only custom field values, there is `save_custom_field_values` method, defined in `acts_as_customizable` module

Answer (score 0):

The problem with above code is, that it works in Redmine 3.4 both in console, and as Rake task, but in Redmine 4, it only works in console.

Eventually I was able to perform change on issue's custom field on Redmine 4 via Rake task in the following way:

```
namespace :redmine do
  namespace :myplugin do
    desc 'Updates custom field for idle tickets.'
    task :update_idle => :environment do
      Issue.open.each do |issue|
        begin
          days = DateTime.now.to_time - DateTime.parse(issue.updated_on.to_s).to_time
          days = days/86400
          if days > 0
            issue.custom_values.each do |x|
              if x.custom_field_id == 19
                x.value = days.ceil
                x.save
              end
             end
            issue.save
            true
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```